# Regex: How can i get both teams of an event as cleanly as possible

Tags: python, regex, string

I have been trying for a while now to successfully parse through bookmaker sites and retrieve markets/odds.

I have come to a point where I fetch the .text attribute of a Selenium web-element so I have something like this:

**Edited to showcase more examples**

```
BPZ vs Griffin - League of Legends - Challenger Korea
Sat 2/25   1511 BPZ 1.645         
10:30PM   1512 Griffin   2.250

Team Battle Comics vs RisingStar Gaming - League of Legends - Challenger Korea
Sat 2/25   1513 Team Battle Comics 5.800         
11:59PM   1514 RisingStar Gaming   1.133

Going In vs Hala Ares - Dota 2 - Prodota Cup
Sat 2/25   1529 Going In 1.667         
1:30PM   1530 Hala Ares   2.200

Unicorns of Love vs G2 Esports - League of Legends - Intel Extreme Masters
Sat 2/25   1545 Unicorns of Love 2.750         
11:15AM   1546 G2 Esports   1.444
```

What I am unable to do after literally hours of googling regex and reading the syntax, is to extract parts of this string as i need them. In the above string, if i could use regex to filter it into a dictionary that would look like this:

```
{'event':'BPZ vs Griffin - League of Legends',
 'outcome1':'BPZ',
 'outcome2':'Griffin',
 'outcome1odds':1.645,
 'outcome2odds':2.25,
 'date':'Sat 2/25',
 'time':'10:30PM'}
```

Then I would be extremely happy. I am fairly sure it is possible, but i am having too many difficulties wrapping my head around regex to achieve it. Any help and/or resources is much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could post more text samples. Regex is all about pattern matching, and it's difficult to discern a pattern from a single example.

Comment: Is the text sample you are showing the exact same format you are always dealing with?

Comment: Are your sets of data always separated by a new line like that? Or did you break that apart?

Comment: Posted more examples. And yes, more or less the same format.

Comment: I broke them apart, I am not a master at formatting im afraid. I hope its feasible as it is.

Comment: What is your approach towards doing this. What have you tried. Show your code so we can understand what it is you are trying to do, to help indicate where your mistake is and what direction you should be taking.

Comment: are there linebreaks in the actual string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using [re.match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) and [match.groupdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.groupdict) (gets all the named subgroups of the match) methods:

```
s = '''
BPZ vs Griffin - League of Legends - Challenger Korea
Sat 2/25   1511 BPZ 1.645
10:30PM   1512 Griffin   2.250
'''
p = r'^(?P<event>[\w ]+-[\w ]+)\s[\w\s-]+' \
    r'(?P<date>[A-Z]\w+ \d+\/\d{2})\s+\d+\s(?P<outcome1>[\w ]+)' \
    r'(?P<outcome1odds>\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<time>\d+:\d+(AM|PM))\s+\d+\s' \
    r'(?P<outcome2>[\w ]+)(?P<outcome2odds>\d+\.\d+)'

matches = re.match(p, s.strip(), re.M)
result = {k:v.strip() for k,v in matches.groupdict().items()}
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'time': '10:30PM', 'event': 'BPZ vs Griffin - League of Legends', 'outcome2odds': '2.250', 'date': 'Sat 2/25', 'outcome2': 'Griffin', 'outcome1': 'BPZ', 'outcome1odds': '1.645'}
```

Comment: Wow, that is some good stuff. I just made a function to process any event output in a matter of seconds from copy/pasting most of your code. Thanks a ton good Sir!

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should do the trick:

```
(?P<event>(?P<outcome1>[^-]+?) vs (?P<outcome2>[^-]+) -.*?) -[^\b]*?(?P<date>(?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) \d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?)[^.]*(?P<outcome1odds>\d+\.\d+)\s+(?P<time>\d+:\d+[AP]M)[^.]*(?P<outcome2odds>\d+\.\d+)
```

It's very long, but in exchange you can use the `.groupdict()` function to directly get your desired result:

```
print(re.match(pattern, text).groupdict())
```

---

Breakdown:

```
(?P<event>          # in a named capture group, match...
    (?P<outcome1>   # outcome1, which is...
        [^-]+?      # all text up to...
    ) 
     vs             # a literal " vs " 
    (?P<outcome2>   # outcome2 is...
        [^-]+       # all text up to...
    )
     -              # the next literal " -"
    .*?             # still inside the "event" group, match until...
)
 -                  # a literal " -"
[^\b]*?             # skip forward to...
(?P<date>           # the date, which is...
    (?:Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) # a weekday
     \d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?   # followed by digits separated with /
)
[^.]*               # skip worward to...
(?P<outcome1odds> 
    \d+\.\d+        # a floating point number
)
\s+
(?P<time>           # match the time, which is...
    \d+:\d+         # digits separated with :
    [AP]M           # followed by AM or PM
)
[^.]*               # skip to...
(?P<outcome2odds> 
    \d+\.\d+        # another floating point number
)
```

Comment: I got Muhamad solution implemented fairly easy, and thus i think i should mark him as the answer (?) Will do for this moment.. but thank you for that detailed breakdown, i had no idea why muhamads solution was working but now i actually am getting it.. Regex is a headache for me.. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

with this long regex, you can find your data in 8 Groups:

```
(.*-.*)\s-\s.*\n(\w{3})\s*(\d+\/\d+)\s*\d+\s*(\w+)\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*\n(\d+\:\d+\w\w)\s*\d+\s*(\w+)\s*(\d+\.?\d*)

Full match  0-104   `BPZ vs Griffin - League of Legends - Challenger Korea Sat 2/25 1511 BPZ 1.645
10:30PM 1512 Griffin 2.250`

Group 1.    n/a `BPZ vs Griffin - League of Legends`
Group 2.    n/a `Sat`
Group 3.    n/a `2/25`
Group 4.    n/a `BPZ`
Group 5.    n/a `1.645`
Group 6.    n/a `10:30PM`
Group 7.    n/a `Griffin`
Group 8.    n/a `2.250`

{'event':'$1',
 'outcome1':'$4',
 'outcome2':'$7',
 'outcome1odds':$5,
 'outcome2odds':$8,
 'date':'$2 $3',
 'time':'$6'}
```

https://regex101.com/r/2IdfnB/2

Comment: That looks very promising Sir! I will give it a go and see how it behaves for me. Thanks for taking time to answer newbie me. :)

Comment: Do you extracting this examples from HTML Table? @TobiasJørgensen

Comment: yes, in my selenium code i find all elements in a table by their classes and then do .text on those to get the output i showcase.

Comment: I can't advice any solution in python because I'm not familiar with it, and now you've found desire answer.